# check of redanduncy

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, js

I'm trying to create new demande of absence which contain start date and end date.
I don't want to have duplicated period of absence that s why I should check that :
-Start date and end date are not duplicated
​​​​​​-when i insert start date and end date, the period between them should be blocked to avoid insert another absence there.

apex code :

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static RL_Demande_absence__c createDemandeAbsence(String employeId, Date startDate, Date endDate, String absenceType) {
 
           List<RL_Demande_absence__c> dates = [SELECT Id,RL_date_debut__c, RL_Date_fin__c 
                                                  From RL_Demande_absence__c
                                                WHERE RL_date_debut__c = : StartDate AND RL_Date_fin__c =:endDate AND RL_ressource__c = :employeId];
      
       
        if(dates.isEmpty() && dates.size()==0){
         RL_Demande_absence__c demande = new RL_Demande_absence__c();
     
        demande.RL_ressource__c = employeId;
        demande.RL_Date_debut__c = startDate;
        demande.RL_Date_fin__c = endDate;
        demande.RL_Type__c = absenceType;
        demande.RL_Statut__c = 'En attente';

        insert demande;
        return demande;
            
        }     
        
        else {
        
            return null; }   
    }
```

js controller :
submitAbsence: function(component, event, helper) {
const recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
const employeId = component.get('v.employeId');
const startDate = component.find('startDate').get('v.value');
const endDate = component.find('endDate').get('v.value');
const absenceType = component.find('type').get('v.value');

```
    if (startDate == null || endDate == null || absenceType == null || absenceType.length == 0) {
        helper.showMessage(component, 'Veuillez remplir tous les informations nécessaires');
        return;
    }

   
    
    
    if (startDate >= endDate) {
        helper.showMessage(component, 'Les dates ne sont pas valables');
        return;
    }

 
    if (recordId == null) {
   
        
        const createDemandeAbsence = component.get('c.createDemandeAbsence');
        createDemandeAbsence.setParams({ employeId, startDate, endDate, absenceType });
        createDemandeAbsence.setCallback(this, response => {
            const state = response.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                                       
                 submitAbsence: function(component, event, helper) {
    const recordId = component.get('v.recordId');
    const employeId = component.get('v.employeId');
    const startDate = component.find('startDate').get('v.value');
    const endDate = component.find('endDate').get('v.value');
    const absenceType = component.find('type').get('v.value');

    if (startDate == null || endDate == null || absenceType == null || absenceType.length == 0) {
        helper.showMessage(component, 'Veuillez remplir tous les informations nécessaires');
        return;
    }

   
    
    
    if (startDate >= endDate) {
        helper.showMessage(component, 'Les dates ne sont pas valables');
        return;
    }

 
    if (recordId == null) {
   
        
        const createDemandeAbsence = component.get('c.createDemandeAbsence');
        createDemandeAbsence.setParams({ employeId, startDate, endDate, absenceType });
        createDemandeAbsence.setCallback(this, response => {
            const state = response.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a look at [ask] and then [edit] your post to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to use the formatting tools on your code (start and end each block with ```, or select and click the `{}` button), and make sure you **ask a specific question**. Please do not just post code and an objective - the community needs to know what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find overlapping dates, you need to change your query:

```
WHERE RL_date_debut__c <= :EndDate AND 
      RL_Date_fin__c >= :StartDate AND 
      RL_ressource__c = :employeId
```

Also, you don't need to check isEmpty and size equal to 0; they mean the same thing.